# spring-boot-docker-compose with gvenzl/oracle-xe not working

Tags: spring-boot

I wanted to migrate from testcontainers to new SpringBoot dependency spring-boot-docker-compose but I'm having some troubles when starting up the container gvenzl/oracle-xe.

With testcontainer, I had the property withStartupTimeout allowing to set some minutes until the message "DATABASE IS READY" is displayed.

But I don't find the same or similar property in spring-boot-docker-compose. I was trying with the properties **spring.docker.compose.readiness.timeout** and **spring.docker.compose.readiness.wait** but spring doesn't seem to wait for.

The container is created and then immediately called but the problem is gvenzl/oracle-xe takes a while to startup

```
2023-09-21T09:32:48.082+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Creating
2023-09-21T09:32:50.616+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Created
2023-09-21T09:32:50.626+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Starting
2023-09-21T09:32:53.957+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Started
2023-09-21T09:32:53.957+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Waiting
2023-09-21T09:32:54.463+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [utReader-stderr] o.s.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli   :  Container oracle-database  Healthy
2023-09-21T09:32:55.714+02:00  INFO 16720 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

Can someone share a working configuration?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is accessing the database immediately and what's the failure that occurs when it does so?